# Creating iOS App With Nav Controller & Login Screen

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an App, it uses the navigation controller to move between various pages. I need to be able to force the user to sign in as it communicates with a web service. I cannot seem to get the sign in to appear by itself, load, all authentication and unload.

I was reading the article on SO, it is to use a subview and insert this into the main view.

This would contain the log in  fields, username, password etc. and would be made invisible after successful authentication. It would then be made visible again on sign out. Is this correct? Is this the best way to do a sign in screen for a multipage App using the navigation controller?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do a log in screen. For me, I had a login controller declared in the delegate. When I want to show the login screen, I call as a modal.

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginScreen animated:YES];
```

Because I have it in the delegate, I can call to show the login screen, wherever I am in the code by hooking back to the delegate.

Anywhere in any controller:

```
AppDelegate *myAppDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[myAppDelegate logout];
```

then in the delegate

```
-(void)logout{
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginScreen animated:YES];
//Do any logging out stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing the same thing than you and here is how I do that.
I have a `ViewController`, let's call it HomeViewController, which is called when my app launches.

In the `ViewDidLoad` method, I check if there is a connected user (some variable in my `AppDelegate`). If yes, I display my HomeViewController, otherwise I display a second view controller (LoginViewController) which handle the WS service call, and the insertion of the password/login.

This way is almost identical than yours. I just split the two views, to avoid too much code in the 'home' one. I didn't find an other way to do that.

And BTW, if you want to move between several pages, there is a great functionality in iOS development: the storyboard.